# Categories and Sub Categories

Tags: templating, craft3

Good morning and thank you in advance. Very to new Craft and Twig so I am not sure if I am coding this correctly but need some help.

I have a forms center that has 5 main categories (Members, Finance, Technology, etc, etc)

On my members landing page, I only want to display forms that are associated to the members category then order those forms by sub categories.

I have got that working, but when I associate a form to another category (say Finance - OTL PALS), the OTL PALS sub category now shows on my members page.

[image: OTL PALS SHOULD NOT SHOW WITH THE TABS. IT IS A FINANCE FROM]

Here is the associated entry image:
[image]

Here is my code... Not even sure if this is the correct way but it is working for the most part. I am pulling the slug (members) to get a list of form entries.

```
<div class="section-bg-color">
    <div class="container content">        
        <div class="text-center">
            <h3>POPULAR FORMS</h3>
        </div>

        {% set categories = craft.categories.group('formLocation') %}
        {% set projects = craft.entries.section('formCenter').relatedTo(craft.categories.slug(craft.app.request.segments|first)).orderby('title').limit(null) %}

        <div class="tab-box pills" data-tab-anima="fade-right">
            <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-center">
                {% for category in categories.relatedTo(projects).all() %}
                    {% if category.level > 1 %}
                        {% set class = "" %}
                        {% if loop.index == 2 %}
                            {% set class = "current-active active" %}
                        {% endif %}
                        <li class="{{ class }}"><a href="#">{{ category.title }}</a></li>
                    {% endif %}
                {% endfor %}                      
            </ul>
            {% for category in categories.relatedTo(projects).all() %}
                {% if category.level > 1 %}
                    {% set class = "" %}
                    {% if loop.index == 2 %}
                        {% set class = "active" %}
                    {% endif %}                    
                    <div class="panel {{ class }} fade-right" style="transition-duration: 300ms; animation-duration: 300ms; transition-timing-function: ease; transition-delay: 0ms;">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-12">
                                <ul class="list-texts text-left">
                                {% for entry in projects.relatedTo(category).all() %}
                                    {% set file = entry.forms.one() %}
                                    {% if file|length %}
                                    <li><a href="{{ file.getUrl() }}" target="_blank">{{ entry.title }}</a></li>
                                    {% endif %}
                                {% endfor %} 
                                </ul>
                            </div>
                        </div>                    
                    </div>
                {% endif %}
            {% endfor %}
        </div>       
</div>
```